# Wire color code on usb to lightning data cable (duracell manufactured by esi)

Tags: usb, wire, colour-coding

Hi so i have two duracell chare cables. One is 6 feet the other 10, the 10 foot broke so I purchased a 6 foot and was going to lengthen it. Since they are both duracell I figured wires would match easily...the 10 foot has red, green, white, and uninsulated wire
The other cable has grey, yellow, pink, and white? What colors goto what?

Cable A 
Red (power) 
Green (data -) 
White (data +) 
Uninsulated wire (ground)

Cable B 
Grey
Neon Yellow
Pink
White

Comment: Grab your DMM and find out.

Comment: I dont have much experience with a dmm, I tried but I couldn’t get any readings

Comment: You need to work on the position of the pins to match the cables. It is not the color but the position in each of the plugs.

Comment: I found my power wire, how can i find my positive data wire?

Comment: Post a link to your actual cable and I'll update my answer.  So far I have assumed it's a passive cable, but if not, the procedure will be very different.

Comment: Duracell Hi-Performance 3 Ft Fast Charging Data Sync & Charge Nylon Braided Fabric Lightening USB Cable MFI Certified for iPhone X 8/8 Plus 7/7 Plus 6/6s Plus, and more - BLACK (NEW 2017-2018 Model) https://www.amazon.com/dp/B075NT5XKY/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_gaIFAbXV9CH0Q Its that ome is 10 feet one is 6,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you don't have much experience with a DMM, here's how you do it:

1) Select "continuity test" mode.  That's the mode that makes the DMM beep when you touch the two leads together.  It will look something like this:[image]

2) From each of the pins on each connector, find the wire that makes the DMM beep.  You should now be able to match the colors and complete the cable.

**EDIT:** Continuity tests will only work to the USB end since the other end includes a chip. (Thanks DoxyLover!)

Comment: Do the testing on the USB end. The Lightning end has a chip built-in so the pins are not directly connected to the wires.

Comment: The Lightning end?  Do you know what specific cable he's talking about?  If it's an active cable, obviously this gets a lot more complicated.

Comment: His title says “usb to lighting data cable”

Comment: Ah... lighting == lightning ;)